# Facebook login button on multiple pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm using the facebook login button on my site and it's working just fine. But, for my site, I use the require_once function to include my header.php file on every page. I know that the site url that's listed on my app setting on fb has to match the page that's has the login button. Is it possible to have the facebook login button on multiple pages? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit your app in developer.facebook.com, you can add app domains. These are domains you can auth from, so you could do example.com and www or www2 or just example.com would allow auth. But you asked about having "login button" from any page, as long as you are not changing domains it should not be a problem. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm a real newbie when it comes to the fb api and programming in general. I had a feeling that it was something simple.

Comment: not a problem, let me know if you need anymore help, if you are a web programming newbie, i like to pump http://www.w3schools.com they helped me get started understanding web dev a while back :)

Comment: Oh yes!! I love that site. Have been going on it for several months now

Comment: How can a user logout of fb thru my site?

Comment: using `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();`, you can use that to provide a link or redirect the user there, if you add a next param like so: `$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'mysite.com'));` when the user clicks it, or you redirect them to the url, it will redirect them to the "next" address after it logs them out

Comment: So, <a href="<?php $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'mysite.com')); ?>">Logout</a>?

Comment: lol, you should be logged out though now. if your "next" is not set up right it wont redirect you.

Comment: Actually, it takes me to fb and i'm not logged out

Comment: Do you know anything about the workings of the graph api and how it pertains to using multiple action in the same post?